# How to make the values of a pandas dataframe column as column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to reshape my dataframe:

from Input_DF

```
col1                                                 col2  col3
Course_66    0\nCourse_67    1\nCourse_68    0       a     c  
Course_66    1\nCourse_67    0\nCourse_68    0       a     d
```

to Output_DF

```
   Course_66       Course_67       Course_68    col2  col3
           0              0                1     a     c  
           0              1                0     a     d
```

Please, note that col1 contains one long string.

Please, any help would be very appreciated. 
Many Thanks in advance.
Best Regards,
Carlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
#first split by whitespaces to df
df1 = df['col1'].str.split(expand=True)
#for each column split by \n and select first value 
df2 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.str.split(r'\\n').str[0])
#for columns select only first row and select second splitted value
df2.columns = df1.iloc[0].str.split(r'\\n').str[1]
print (df2)
0 Course_66 Course_67 Course_68
0         0         0         1
1         0         1         0

#join to original, remove unnecessary column
df = df2.join(df.drop('col1', axis=1))
print (df)
  Course_66 Course_67 Course_68 col2 col3
0         0         0         1    a    c
1         0         1         0    a    d
```

Another solution with `list` comprehension:

```
L = [[y.split('\\n')[0] for y in x.split()] for x in df['col1']]
cols = [x.split('\\n')[1] for x in df.loc[0, 'col1'].split()]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index, columns=cols)
print (df1)
  Course_66 Course_67 Course_68
0         0         0         1
1         0         1         0
```

EDIT:

```
#split values by whitespaces - it split by \n too
df1 = df['course_vector'].str.split(expand=True)
#select each pair columns
df2 = df1.iloc[:, 1::2]
#for columns select each unpair value in first row
df2.columns = df1.iloc[0, 0::2]
#join to original
df = df2.join(df.drop('course_vector', axis=1))
```

Comment: I wish I could vote but my voting limit exceed for today

Comment: Thanks you very much Jezrael. However, when I apply your first solution to my data, I got the following: `0          NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        NaN NaN        
0    Course_31   0  Course_3A   0  Course_47   1  Course_48   0  Course_5B   0  Course_5C   0  Course_5D   0  Course_5E   0  Course_5F   0  Course_60   0` . The second solution I cannot use it as my input dataframe contains index as a column.

Comment: Hmmm, your data are very specific, maybe are a bit different. Is possible create picle file with first 5 rows and send it to my email if not confidental data? `df.head().to_pickle('file.pkl')`

Comment: Just did it. please, let me know if you received it. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data are ordered in value, key pairs, you can split on newlines and multiple spaces with regex to get a list, and then take every other value starting at the first position for values and the second position for labels and return a `Series` object.  By applying, you will get back a DataFrame from these multiple series, which you can then combine with the original `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['0\nCourse_66    0\nCourse_67    1\nCourse_68',                                                                                                                                                               
                            '0\nCourse_66    1\nCourse_67    0\nCourse_68'],                                                                                                                                                              
                'col2': ['a', 'a'], 'col3': ['c', 'd']})                                                                                                                                                                                  

def to_multiple_columns(str_list):                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    # take the numeric values for each series and column labels and return as a series                                                                                                                                                    
    # by taking every other value                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    return pd.Series(str_list[::2], str_list[1::2])                                                                                                                                                                                       

# split on newlines and spaces                                                                                                                                                                                                                
splits = df['col1'].str.split(r'\n|\s+').apply(to_multiple_columns)                                                                                                                                                                       

output = pd.concat([splits, df.drop('col1', axis=1)], axis=1)                                                                                                                                                                             
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
  Course_66 Course_67 Course_68 col2 col3
0         0         0         1    a    c
1         0         1         0    a    d
```

Comment: Thank you very much benjwadams. I realized that I have got an issue on my input data that is not as I reported above in the input dataframe. Unfortunately, I cannot apply your solution. Thanks you very much for your effort.

Comment: I changed the input dataset as reported in my orginal data. However, your assumption "are ordered in value," is not true in my data. It is just a coincidence.